How to set up this French bibliographic style?
I have to use a french specific bibliographic style:

First, when I quote a book, this one must be indicated in a footnote in the following style: first name and last name without comma, book title, year of publication, city, publisher.
When I quote the same book for the second time, this one must be inserted into a footnote in. the following style: first name and last name without comma, book title, op. cit., page number.
When I quote this one immediately after, it must be inserted the following mention in a footnote: Ibid., page number.
Or, if it's the same page number, only: Ibid.
The abbreviations op. cit. and Ibid. must be displayed in italics.
The same principle must applied for any kind of reference: journal, book chapter, and so on.
How could I do that? This is a MWE.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Bertrand2005,
author = {Bertrand, Michèle}, 
title = {Qu'est-ce que la subjectivation ?}, 
journal = {Le Carnet Psy}, 
volume = {96}, 
number = {1}, 
pages = {24--27}, 
year = {2005}, 

}

@book{Winnicott1975,
address   = {Paris},
author    = {Winnicott, Donald Woods},
publisher = {Éditions Gallimard},
title     = {Jeu et réalité},
subtitle  = {L'espace potentiel},
year      = {1975},

}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
This is a book reference\footcite{Winnicott1975}, the same book\footcite{Winnicott1975} and an article\footcite{Bertrand2005}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


You mean footnote bibliography? take a look a this maybe: How to embed citations into footnotes?

@DavidBarcene It's an ad hoc setup I'm looking for: in a footnote, I must be able to cite a reference in the way indicated.

First of all, change the style to the derived verbose-trad1. It already has got many of the features you're looking for.
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

Please, remind to load the csquotes package.
\usepackage{csquotes}

Regarding the author, here are the changes I made. I need to explain them in detail because I'm not sure exactly what you asked for. So, for the full author name (prénom and nom), you need to add these commands. These will also prevent the first and last name from being switched around.
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{default}

So, this lets any name appearing in full and in the correct order.
Then, I'm not sure if you want the author's name to be written in small capital letters. If not, add this command. Otherwise, by default, biblatex will print the last name in capital letters.
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

I'll explain the separator between names and the work's title (to remove the comma, as you wish) later.
To let the title of the work be in italics, use these commands.
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference,article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

The second command is necessary to let the title of any kind of source be in italics: sources like journal articles, book chapters and essays in collections. You need to put the types of sources you want to have italicised titles for inside square brackets. I considered the @inbook, @incollection, @inproceedings, @inreference and @article drivers.
Remind to update the citetitle format as well. This format controls the title fields of the works you cite on the second and subsequent occasions.
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,article]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

To control the punctuation between the author and title, both in (the first) citations and in the bibliography, I think the only way is to modify the basic title macro. So, if I misunderstood your excerpt about «first name and last name without comma», skip this part.
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\setunit{\space}%
        \printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \printfield{titleaddon}}

In my comment, I wrote «the first» in parentheses: indeed, to remove the comma between the author and title in subsequent citations, you need to modify this other macro
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

Turning our attention to the commands for abbreviations in subsequent citations, we need to first custom a specific format that we can use later to italicise the strings.
\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\textit{#1}}

Now, look back to the cite:title macro (see above): this is used when you cite a particular source for the second and subsequent times. As requested, I have inserted the opcit string, which is printed in italics (see the \mkibid command).
I then modified the cite:opcit macro. This macro is used when you cite a source when is the same as the last one by the same author: by default, would only print the string 'op. cit.'. However, I adjusted this macro so that the title of the work is always printed as well."
\renewbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}}

The cite:ibid macro governs citations that are identical to the previous one. In this case, the string should not be the opcit, but rather the ibid. This customisation makes sure that, when you cite and indicate a page number and when that page number matches, LaTeX omits it and only prints «Ibid.»; if the page numbers don't match, or if at least one of the two citations doesn't have a page number, LaTeX will behave as it normally does.
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
    \printtext{%
        \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    \ifboolexpr{togl {cbx:ibidpage}%
                and
                test {\ifloccit}}%
        {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}%
        {}%
    \ifloccit%
        {\clearfield{postnote}}%
        {}}

The modification of the next macro (publisher+location+date) ensures that, for the @book driver and the similars, the order of the address of publication, publisher and year of publication will be as you specified
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \newunit}

Finally, I rewrote the next three macros, which relate to the @article driver. I've changed them so that the year comes before the information about the volume and issue number. It seems to me consistent with the citation style you requested, which, in the @book and similar drivers, puts the year of publication before the publisher and place of publication. So, it's just an extra petita.
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{volume}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}%
        {\setunit*{\adddot}}%
        {\newunit}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}

One last thing: if you want the main punctuation mark in your citation to be a comma instead of a period, insert this command. This won't affect the previous changes.
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

In this case, you may wish to set the specific separator between the title and subtitle. The command is \subtitlepunct and you may set it so that the separator is a dot followed by a space, no matter which is the main \newunitpunct.
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\adddot\space}

That's all. Just a final recap of the previous commands (except for these two about the main punctuation mark and the separator between the title and the subtitle) into a single area.
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{default}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference,article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,article]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{title}}%
                and
                test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}}%
        {}%
        {\setunit{\space}%
        \printtext[title]{%
        \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
        \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
        \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
        \newunit}%
    \printfield{titleaddon}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
    \printtext{%
        \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
        \bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}%
    \ifboolexpr{togl {cbx:ibidpage}%
                and
                test {\ifloccit}}%
        {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}%
        {}%
    \ifloccit%
        {\clearfield{postnote}}%
        {}}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \newunit}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% extra petita %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \newunit%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}
    \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{volume}}%
                and
                not test {\iffieldundef{number}}}%
        {\setunit*{\adddot}}%
        {\newunit}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}}%
    \newunit}


What a work you've done! Merci !
